# Simulate a Detail Disclosure Button press

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Does anyone know of a way to simulate pressing a detail disclosure button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the following to simulate a click on a table row:

```
[self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Perhaps something like this would work?

```
[self tableView:self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

Not tried it but assume it should be okay.