# Automatically drill down through navigation hierarchy?

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation, hierarchy

I have a navigation-based app that allows the user to drill down through hierarchies. Some of the child hierarchies have only one element in them, e.g.,

```
TopLevel1----->Level2a
TopLevel2   |->Level2b----->Level3a----->Level4a
            |->Level2c
```

Instead of making the user tap 'Level3a', I just want to jump from Level2b to Level4a, but keep the Level3a view in the stack so when the user backtracks, it is visible.

I found some code here to simulate a row tap:

[Simulate a Detail Disclosure Button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841270)

When each level is loaded, I check to see if there is only one element in it. If so, I simulate the row tap. This all works initially, and the final view is loaded. But when I start backtracking through the view hierarchy, I get problems (it appears that the skipped views aren't loaded).

I think what I'm trying to accomplish is fairly simple, so I'm hoping someone on here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place a `[self.navigationController pushViewController:level4 animated:NO]` call in the `viewWillAppear` method for your level3 view controller. This will automatically push level4 on top of level3.

If it only happens some of the time, level3 can have a property to indicate when this behavior takes place.

Comment: Thanks, but that gives me the same result. Actually, using animated:NO gives me very weird results. If I change it to animated:YES, I get the same result as using the simulated row tap code. I'm digging through my code to try to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that would work, but that's what I would do.

You could directly `[self.navigationController pushViewController:level4a animated:NO]` and when that's done, set a new array of `viewControllers`, the `navigationController` propriety (an array that includes `Level3a`).

Here is a code sample, in you `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:level4a animated:NO]; //Push the level 4 first
NSMutableArray* mutableViewControllers = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[mutableViewController addObject:level3a atIndex:3]; //Add the level 3 manually
self.navigationController.viewControllers = mutableViewControllers;
[mutableViewControllers release];
```